# php array combine and use value as index/key

Tags: php, arrays

how do i combine these arrays and use a specific value as key/index?
here's sample array i'm playing with:

```
Array  
(  
    [0]=>john   
    [1]=>peter  
)  

Array  
(  
    [dept]=>engineering  
    [sub]=>trigonometry  
    [time]=>08:00  
 )
```

what i want to achieved is like this:

```
Array  
(  
    [john]=>john  
    [dept]=>engineering  
    [sub]=>trigonometry  
    [time]=>08:00    

    [peter]=>peter
    [dept]=>engineering  
    [sub]=>trigonometry  
    [time]=>08:00   
)
```

thanks in advance guys, hope u can help me with this. appreciate it.

Comment: What you want to achieve cannot be achieved because it has duplicate keys

Comment: what php code u have used to fetch this records?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to associate the value of the first array with the values of the second array.

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($firstArray as $name) {
    $finalArray[$name] = $secondArray;
}
print_r($finalArray);
```

You will get :

```
Array
(
    [john] => Array
              (
                  [dept]=>engineering  
                  [sub]=>trigonometry  
                  [time]=>08:00  
              )
    [peter] => Array
              (
                  [dept]=>engineering  
                  [sub]=>trigonometry  
                  [time]=>08:00  
              )
)
```

Does this help you?